# C# List to DataTable extension method not retrieving properties

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, extension-methods

I want to convert a ObservableCollection of type KNMOLijst to a DataTable. I found a extension method for it, but it is not retrieving my properties?

Extension method:

```
public static class ListToDataTable
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
                var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

The peace of code below is not retrieving any properties, I also tried to include the nonpublic members in the bindingflags, but that didn't seem to work for me

```
//Get all the properties
PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This is the type KNMOLijst it receives:

```
   public class KNMOLijst
        {
            public string VoorLetters { get; set; }

            public string Voornaam { get; set; }

            public string TussenVoegsel { get; set; }

            public string Achternaam { get; set; }

            public string Geslacht { get; set; }

            public DateTime GeboorteDatum { get; set; }

            public string InstrumentNaam { get; set; }

            public KNMOLijst()
            {

            }
        }
```

I made sure that the properties were public.

This is the list that the extension method receives.

```
generatedList.Add(new KNMOLijst()
                {
                    VoorLetters = (string)(row["VoorLetters"]),
                    Voornaam = (string)(row["Voornaam"]),
                    TussenVoegsel = (string)(row["TussenVoegsel"]),
                    Achternaam = (string)row["Achternaam"],
                    Geslacht = (string)row["Geslacht"],
                    GeboorteDatum = (DateTime)row["GeboorteDatum"],
                    InstrumentNaam = (string)row["InstrumentNaam"]
                });
```

My viewmodel that invokes the ToDataTable method.

```
public class SecretarisViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly SecretarisBLL secretarisBll;

        private ObservableCollection<object> generatedList;

        public ObservableCollection<object> GeneratedList
        {
            get { return generatedList; }
            set
            {
                generatedList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private DataTable generatiedDataTable;

        public DataTable GeneratedDataTable
        {
            get => generatiedDataTable;
            set
            {
                generatiedDataTable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public SecretarisViewModel()
        {
            secretarisBll = new SecretarisBLL();
            GeneratedList = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            generatiedDataTable = new DataTable();
        }

        public async Task GetKNMOList()
        {
            var dataset = await secretarisBll.GetKNMOList();

            foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                generatedList.Add(new KNMOLijst()
                {
                    VoorLetters = (string)(row["VoorLetters"]),
                    Voornaam = (string)(row["Voornaam"]),
                    TussenVoegsel = (string)(row["TussenVoegsel"]),
                    Achternaam = (string)row["Achternaam"],
                    Geslacht = (string)row["Geslacht"],
                    GeboorteDatum = (DateTime)row["GeboorteDatum"],
                    InstrumentNaam = (string)row["InstrumentNaam"]
                });
            }

            GeneratedDataTable = generatedList.ToDataTable();
        }
    }
```

Why is it not able to get the properties of my list?

Comment: What is `T` -- what is the type of `generatedList`? If it's anything but something implementing `IList<KNMOLijst>`, it won't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the type of the List correct? The code works for me.

Comment: Checked with your sample and worked. So i guess that your `row` doesn't contain the values.

Comment: can you add the code where you invoke ToDataTable Method?

Comment: @JeroenMostert The generatedlist is an ObservableCollection<object>, so I assume that if I would add a new KNMOLijst row into it, it would be of the type KNMOLijst?

Comment: You assume wrongly. The type is resolved statically (at compile time), so this will call `typeof(object).GetProperties`, which of course retrieves nothing. Either make your collection strongly typed, or tweak the extension method to use `(items.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType() ?? typeof(T))`, so it reflects over an actual object if the list has any elements. (If the list is empty, though, this produces a table without columns, which might cause code to fail.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ohhh okay yeah you are right! Would you mind explaining me how I could tweak my extension method to work only on non-empty lists? If I am honest I am new to this and do not yet fully understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The generatedlist is an `ObservableCollection<object>`,
>   so I assume that if I would add a new KNMOLijst row into it, it would
>   be of the type KNMOLijst?

No, if the list is of type `ObservableCollection<object>` then `T` is `System.Object` which has no public properties. So make it a `ObservableCollection<KNMOLijst>`.

If you can't do that modify the method to derive the type from the first item:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> items)
{
    Type type = items.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType();
    if (type == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The properties are derived from the first item, so the list must not be empty");

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(type.Name);
    //Get all the properties
    PropertyInfo[] Props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // ...
}
```

By the way, this behavior(throwing `InvalidOperationException` on empty list) is similar to [`CopyToDataTable`](http://InvalidOperationException) which does the same. It also needs to use reflection to get the columns.

Comment: I tried this, but in debugging it skipped the type check. This is what type contains when it gets to that line: {Name = "KNMOLijst" FullName = "Gildenbondsharmonie.BO.Lists.KNMOLijst"}. But it is still not receiving my properties?

Comment: @Brum: skipped which type check?

Comment: That part: Type type = items.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType();
    if (type == null)
        type = typeof(T); 
 but I am going to include an screenshot of what is in items.

Comment: @Brum: i have checked the method with your sample and declared it as `ObservableCollection<Object>`. Before my changes it didn't work because `System.Object` was used as type, now it works.

Comment: You my man, are my hero! I didnt notice one chance you made and when I changed in my code it worked. Thank you for your timeI really appreciate it!

Comment: @Brum: modified the method to throw an exception if the list is empty which is better and also consistent with [`CopyToDataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2).